# Correct display of Currency TWD

Tags: java, locale, chinese-locale

I'm not native to Taiwan, nor do I have any knowledge of Taiwanese Mandarin. Hence it could be that all is as intended. My observation:

```java
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.TAIWAN); 
format.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance("TWD")); 

System.out.println(format.format(1600));
```

Results in `$1,600.00`. This might indicate to a reader the US Dollar, not the new Taiwan dollar (TWD). But TWD uses as symbol `NT$`, hence I would assume the correct result to be `NT$ 1,600.00`. Debugging indicates that the NumberFormat construction evaluates to a Symbol set in which $ is a default prefix - but before digging too much into details. Is this the intended behavior?

- Tested on OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-18.0.2.9.1 (build 18.0.2+9-FR).

Comment: See also `Locale.CANADA` A lot of countries use the name "dollar" as the name of their currency name - eg Singapore Australia ... The number format (I believe) is for the convention of the numbers not the currency symbol - eg some countries might print commas and period the other way "1.600,00", or might prefer to pre-pend "US" when referring to USD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be intended. Based on the [list of Currency symbols on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_symbol#List_of_currency_symbols_currently_in_use), most of the different dollar currencies like `Can$`/`C$` (Canadian dollar) or `NT$`/`元/圓` (New Taiwan Dollar) (see third column of the table) still use simply `$` as actual symbol (see first column of the table).

There are some currencies where a letter + `$` is actually the symbol, like the Nicaraguan córdoba for example with `C$`, for which the Java symbol and formatting is as expected with `C$`: [try it online](https://tio.run/##dY@7agMxEEV7f8WwlbawcJo0wZUhsGA2AaczKcbyRGijh5FGxib42zfyrl@Nqwszd85hOtzjtNv@9r2ymBJ8xqAjur8JwC5vrFGQGLnEPpgtODRerDgar9ffWJ9bAF1BSKYDyza7DcX3EB0y/Iwxf7KXmniRYySvjo0vEq9IDNXMxsplUGhJFsgSvc6o6Qu1qChN26aq67fBPCpkupMeCNfRWXQTVG3zMZwP96tjYnIyZJa78hNbLy7IMcTL62xW2lDap8mp7/8B).